# Opacity vs visibility attribute and specificity for SVG elements

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, css-specificity

I have an SVG element I created that I want to animate in parts. The first animation works as intended ('draw' paths to create outline of text), but then I want the rest of the SVG (fill colors, gradients, drop-shadows, etc.) to fade in. I have the following CodePen: https://codepen.io/klarson32907/pen/MNQoLo

At the moment, it does what I want, but there is a brief moment where the entire SVG has `opacity: 0;` which is jarring. So far I've tried setting the initial opacity to 0 for the whole SVG element, hoping that I can animate the opacity with a more specific selector. When I do this, however, the opacity never changes from 0, even with the `!important` declaration. Sorry in advance for the wall of code.

Could someone please explain why the rules for specificity in HTML/CSS aren't equally applicable for SVG/CSS?

```css
.draw {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: draw 3s forwards 1;
}

.logoFinal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -320px;
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: show 2.5s forwards 3s;
}

 @keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 400;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 200 0;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }  
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="640" height="640" class="logoFinal">
  <defs>
    <path d="M330.24 157.71l127.05 127.6-127.6 127.05-127.05-127.6 127.6-127.05z" id="b"/>
    <radialGradient id="c" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="290.77" cy="171.67" r="158.19">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f2f2f2"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#414141"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <path d="M291.55 400c5.18 0 9.92-2.92 12.26-7.55 5.54-10.99 19.39-38.48 41.56-82.45 26.97 44.43 43.82 72.19 50.56 83.3 2.53 4.16 7.04 6.7 11.91 6.7H420l-64.38-110c29.6-59.77 48.1-97.13 55.5-112.08 4.09-8.25-1.91-17.92-11.12-17.92L290 380V160h-2.62c-9.6 0-17.38 7.78-17.38 17.38v206.69c0 8.8 7.13 15.93 15.93 15.93h5.62z" id="e"/>
    <radialGradient id="f" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="238.05" cy="183.42" r="211.69">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#2900d8"/>
      <stop offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <path d="M380 275v20l47.55 90h20l-50-100 50-100h-20L380 275z" id="h"/>
    <radialGradient id="i" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="365.61" cy="204.52" r="161.87">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#2900d8"/>
      <stop offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <path d="M257.55 275v20L210 385h-20l50-100-50-100h20l47.55 90z" id="k"/>
    <radialGradient id="l" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="271.94" cy="204.52" r="161.87">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#2900d8"/>
      <stop offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <filter id="a" x="142.64" y="97.71" width="378.65" height="380.65" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <feFlood/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4.8"/>
    <feOffset dx="4" dy="6" result="afterOffset"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".5"/>
    <feComposite in2="afterOffset" operator="in"/>
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="3"/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out"/>
  </filter>
  <path d="M330.24 157.71l127.05 127.6-127.6 127.05-127.05-127.6 127.6-127.05z" fill="#fff" filter="url(#a)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#b" fill="url(#c)"/>
  <filter id="d" x="219" y="109" width="256" height="346" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <feFlood/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4.47"/>
    <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="afterOffset"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".5"/>
    <feComposite in2="afterOffset" operator="in"/>
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="2"/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out"/>
  </filter>
  <path d="M291.55 400c5.18 0 9.92-2.92 12.26-7.55 5.54-10.99 19.39-38.48 41.56-82.45 26.97 44.43 43.82 72.19 50.56 83.3 2.53 4.16 7.04 6.7 11.91 6.7H420l-64.38-110c29.6-59.77 48.1-97.13 55.5-112.08 4.09-8.25-1.91-17.92-11.12-17.92L290 380V160h-2.62c-9.6 0-17.38 7.78-17.38 17.38v206.69c0 8.8 7.13 15.93 15.93 15.93h5.62z" fill="#fff" filter="url(#d)"/>
  <use class="fill" xlink:href="#e" fill="url(#f)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#e" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" class="draw"/>
  <filter id="g" x="329" y="134" width="173.55" height="306" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <feFlood/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4.47"/>
    <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="afterOffset"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".5"/>
    <feComposite in2="afterOffset" operator="in"/>
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="2"/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out"/>
  </filter>
  <path d="M380 275v20l47.55 90h20l-50-100 50-100h-20L380 275z" fill="#fff" filter="url(#g)"/>
  <use class="fill" xlink:href="#h" fill="url(#i)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#h" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" class="draw"/>
  <g>
    <filter id="j" x="139" y="134" width="173.55" height="306" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feFlood/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4.47"/>
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="afterOffset"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".5"/>
      <feComposite in2="afterOffset" operator="in"/>
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="2"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out"/>
    </filter>
    <path d="M257.55 275v20L210 385h-20l50-100-50-100h20l47.55 90z" fill="#fff" filter="url(#j)"/>
    <use class="fill" xlink:href="#k" fill="url(#l)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#k" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" class="draw"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started by reformatting your SVG a little.  Moving all the gradients, filters, and referenced paths into `<defs>`. Then grouping the other elements based on whether they are part of the final logo, or the drawn outline.

Once you do that, the CSS becomes a bit more straightforward.  You don't need to use `visibility`.  Just set the initial conditions you want. Then animate them in at the right time.

```css
.logoFinal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -320px;
}

.draw {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 400;
  animation: draw 3s forwards 1s;
}

.logo {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 2.5s forwards 3s;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 400;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 200 0;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }  
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="640" height="640" class="logoFinal">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="c" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="290.77" cy="171.67" r="158.19">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f2f2f2"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#414141"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="f" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="238.05" cy="183.42" r="211.69">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#2900d8"/>
      <stop offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="i" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="365.61" cy="204.52" r="161.87">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#2900d8"/>
      <stop offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="l" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="271.94" cy="204.52" r="161.87">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#2900d8"/>
      <stop offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>

    <filter id="a" x="142.64" y="97.71" width="378.65" height="380.65" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feFlood/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4.8"/>
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="6" result="afterOffset"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".5"/>
      <feComposite in2="afterOffset" operator="in"/>
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="3"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out"/>
    </filter>

    <filter id="d" x="219" y="109" width="256" height="346" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feFlood/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4.47"/>
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="afterOffset"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".5"/>
      <feComposite in2="afterOffset" operator="in"/>
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="2"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out"/>
    </filter>

    <filter id="g" x="329" y="134" width="173.55" height="306" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feFlood/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4.47"/>
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="afterOffset"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".5"/>
      <feComposite in2="afterOffset" operator="in"/>
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="2"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out"/>
    </filter>

    <filter id="j" x="139" y="134" width="173.55" height="306" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feFlood/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4.47"/>
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="afterOffset"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".5"/>
      <feComposite in2="afterOffset" operator="in"/>
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="2"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out"/>
    </filter>

    <path d="M330.24 157.71l127.05 127.6-127.6 127.05-127.05-127.6 127.6-127.05z" id="b"/>
    <path d="M291.55 400c5.18 0 9.92-2.92 12.26-7.55 5.54-10.99 19.39-38.48 41.56-82.45 26.97 44.43 43.82 72.19 50.56 83.3 2.53 4.16 7.04 6.7 11.91 6.7H420l-64.38-110c29.6-59.77 48.1-97.13 55.5-112.08 4.09-8.25-1.91-17.92-11.12-17.92L290 380V160h-2.62c-9.6 0-17.38 7.78-17.38 17.38v206.69c0 8.8 7.13 15.93 15.93 15.93h5.62z" id="e"/>
    <path d="M380 275v20l47.55 90h20l-50-100 50-100h-20L380 275z" id="h"/>
    <path d="M257.55 275v20L210 385h-20l50-100-50-100h20l47.55 90z" id="k"/>
  </defs>

  <g class="logo">
    <path d="M330.24 157.71l127.05 127.6-127.6 127.05-127.05-127.6 127.6-127.05z" fill="#fff" filter="url(#a)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#b" fill="url(#c)"/>
    <path d="M291.55 400c5.18 0 9.92-2.92 12.26-7.55 5.54-10.99 19.39-38.48 41.56-82.45 26.97 44.43 43.82 72.19 50.56 83.3 2.53 4.16 7.04 6.7 11.91 6.7H420l-64.38-110c29.6-59.77 48.1-97.13 55.5-112.08 4.09-8.25-1.91-17.92-11.12-17.92L290 380V160h-2.62c-9.6 0-17.38 7.78-17.38 17.38v206.69c0 8.8 7.13 15.93 15.93 15.93h5.62z" fill="#fff" filter="url(#d)"/>
    <use class="fill" xlink:href="#e" fill="url(#f)"/>
    <path d="M380 275v20l47.55 90h20l-50-100 50-100h-20L380 275z" fill="#fff" filter="url(#g)"/>
    <use class="fill" xlink:href="#h" fill="url(#i)"/>
    <path d="M257.55 275v20L210 385h-20l50-100-50-100h20l47.55 90z" fill="#fff" filter="url(#j)"/>
    <use class="fill" xlink:href="#k" fill="url(#l)"/>
  </g>

  <g class="draw">
    <use xlink:href="#e" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"/>
    <use xlink:href="#h" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"/>
    <use xlink:href="#k" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I had the visibility attribute added as a shortcut to make sure the 'look' I was going for was feasible, and I had been stuck using just opacity so I added it in to the mix. May I ask how you were able to pick the SVG apart and determine what could be moved to defs? I'm new to SVGs, so even a reference link would be helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Mostly I just moved all the filters and gradients into `<defs>`. Those are not directly rendered.  They are referenced from elements that *are* rendered. Most SVGs keep them there.  Everything outside `<defs>` I kept in the same order as they were in the original file. Except that I grouped the logo parts together in one `<g>` and the "drawn" parts in the other.

Comment: So if I'm understanding, the `<path>` element won't render unless referenced outside `<defs>`? It's just an empty set of coordinates until 'filled' with a stroke, filter, etc.?

Comment: Yes. A `<path>` in a `<defs>` section won't be directly rendered. But it can be referenced via a `<use>`, and will be rendered then.

Answer (score 0):

Two main problems here.

First, the flash of invisibility makes sense because, after you've animated certain parts of the SVG, you then go and set the opacity of the *entire* SVG to zero in the first step of your `show` animation.

To fix that, you need to change your selector to only select the parts of the SVG that you aren't animating in the `draw` animation. A quick and dirty selector here would be something like `.logoFinal defs ~ *:not(.draw)`, though ideally you'd do a little testing with this and/or try to simplify the SVG markup to narrow that selector down in order to reduce the total number of elements you're animating at once.

Once that's fixed, we then introduce a new problem, which is that `opacity` won't work on, say, a `path`. Instead, use `fill-opacity`.

Putting it together:

```
.draw {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: draw 3s forwards 1;
}

.logoFinal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -320px;
  visibility: hidden;
  /* animation: show 2.5s forwards 3s; */
}

.logoFinal defs ~ *:not(.draw) {
  visibility: hidden;
  fill-opacity: 0;
  animation: show 2.5s forwards 3s;
}

 @keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 400;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 200 0;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }  
}
```

Comment: This was definitely a part of the issue i was having, but the SVG refactor in the first response cleared up the code for me. I understood what the initial flash of invisibility was from, it was just the closest I could get to the ideal animation I had in my head. I'm very new to SVGs and appreciate the info on opacity vs. fill-opacity attributes.

Comment: I also like the crafty CSS selector ` ~ *:not(.draw)` you used!